# Clone content in another part of document?

Tags: text

Is it possible to clone a part of a document in another part of the document? So that changing one, changes both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: there's for example `text-clone-create` which can be used for that (typically used for small chunks of text such as the tag names in XML's tag pairs), as well as the [lentic](https://github.com/phillord/lentic) package.

Comment: Thanks for answering! You mention it is for small texts, but what about entire paragraphs or even an entire outline? Would it still work?

Comment: `text-clone-create` was not designed for large chunks of text.  It might work, but buyer beware.  `lentic` OTOH was designed to keep whole buffers in sync, so it should work fine even for large chunks of text.